# Bug in R Shiny checkbox groups

Tags: r, shiny

I've encountered a strange bug with an app I'm working on. I am seeing inconsistent outputs in `verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1")`. Once the app has loaded:

1. Select 'c' under 'Firms'. Note that `res1` doesn't update.
2. Select 'a' under 'Consumers'. Notice how 'c' suddenly appears in the output.
3. Select 'b'. All outputs are now showing as expected.
4. De-select 'c' and 'd'. Notice that `res1` doesn't update again
5. De-select 'a' or 'b'. Notice how 'c' and 'd' now disappear.

Can anyone think why this is happening? Is it a possible issue with `Map` or have I encountered a `Shiny` bug?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

choices = list('Consumers' = c('a', 'b'), 
               'Firms' = c('c', 'd'))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  column(
    12,
    Map(function(x, y) checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "id1", label=h4(y), choices=x, selected='d'), choices, names(choices)),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$res1 <- renderPrint({
    input$id1
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You are using the same `inputId` for two input widgets. That's bad.

Comment: ...and you're assigning a `reactive` to an `output` element.  That's odd...

Comment: You're both quite correct, of course. I've updated my original question with less terrible Shiny code. I'm still experencing the same issue, however.

Comment: You are still using the same id.

Comment: I clearly don't understand what you mean then. I thought I only had 1 input widget (`checkboxGroupInput`) which I've given the id "id1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Map` command generates a list of two `checkboxGroupInput`:

```
> Map(function(x, y) checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "id1", label=h4(y), choices=x, selected='d'), choices, names(choices))
$Consumers
<div id="id1" class="form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container" role="group" aria-labelledby="id1-label">
......

$Firms
<div id="id1" class="form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container" role="group" aria-labelledby="id1-label">
......
```

They have the same `id`, and this explains the bad behavior.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, very much appreciated. My ignorance of the inner workings of `Map` is clearly on display this evening. Do you know whether it's possible to prevent `Map` from creating `checkboxGroupInput` twice? I used `Map` off the back of a different question a week or so ago; I'm only using it so I can created headings from a nested list of choices.

Comment: @Simon I don't understand what you are expecting. You have some choices for `Consumers` and some choices for `Firms`. What kind of `checkboxGroupInput` are you expecting? It seems that you want two different labels, so I don't understand how do you expect a single widget.

Comment: The choices all need to be within a single input object; having `input$Consumers` and `input$Firms` won't work for my particular use case. Looking at `shinyWidgets::pickInput`, you can actually pass a nested list of choices; 'Consumers' and 'Firms' become the headings, the elements within become the choices.

Comment: I note that I could do the following, but I'm not sure if it's best practice:
`output$res1 <- renderText({x <- c(input$Consumers, input$Firms)})`